# Perform JavaScript .replace in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

How would I perform the following in jQuery?

```
var elmOperator = document.getElementById(elm.id.replace('Include', 'Operator'));
```

The `ID` that is being manipulated would look something like `Criteria[0].Include`.  I am trying to create a variable for a related `ID` which is `Criteria[0].Operator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming elm is a jQuery object, not a DOM object, you could do this:

```
var elmOperator = $("#" + elm.attr('id').replace('Include', 'Operator'));
```

If it is a DOM object, you can do this (which would be a tiny bit faster):

```
var elmOperator = $("#" + elm.id.replace('Include', 'Operator'));
```

The bigger question is why you'd want to do this.  If you don't know something as basic as the [jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) and `attr()`, is your page using jQuery at all anywhere?

Comment: in your second example, if you already had a DOM element, i wouldn't convert it to a jQuery object. it's a lot more overhead and more typing to boot. Compare: "$(elm).attr('id')" to "elm.id"

Answer (score 0):

You can still use old javascript in jQuery so for your sample it would be something like this:

```
var operators = $('[id*=Include]').map(function() {
    return $('#' + $(this).get(0).id.replace('Include', 'Operator'));
});
operators.css('background', 'red');
```

In this sample we are selecting all the Include elements and then performing a 1:1 mapping of the elements to a new array of operator elements, finally we are setting all the operators background to red.